# Cannot allocate exclusively a CPU for my process

Tags: multithreading, scheduler, affinity, cpu-cores, cpuset

I have a simple mono-threaded application that does almost pure processing

> 1. It uses two int buffers of the same size
> 2. It reads one-by-one all the values of the first buffer
>
>    - each value is a random index in the second buffer
> 3. It reads the value at the index in the second buffer
> 4. It sums all the values taken from the second buffer
> 5. It does all the previous steps for bigger and bigger
> 6. At the end, I print the number of voluntary and involuntary CPU context switches

**If the size of the buffers become quite big, my PC starts to slow down: why?** I have 4 cores with hyper-threading so 3 cores are remaing. Only one is 100% busy. Is it because my process uses almost 100% for the "RAM-bus"?

Then, I created a CPU-set that I want to dedicate to my process (my CPU-set contains both CPU-threads of the same core)

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/topology/core_id 
3
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/topology/core_id 
3

$ cset set -c 3,7 -s my_cpuset
$ cset set -l
cset: 
         Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
         root        0-7 y       0 y   934    1 /
    my_cpuset        3,7 n       0 n     0    0 /my_cpuset
```

It seems that absolutely no task at all is running on my CPU-set. I can relaunch my process and while it is running, I launch:

```
$ taskset -c 7 ./TestCpuset # Here, I launch my process
...
$ ps -mo pid,tid,fname,user,psr -p 25244 # 25244 being the PID of my process
  PID   TID COMMAND  USER     PSR
25244     - TestCpus phil       -
    - 25244 -        phil       7
```

PSR = 7: my process is well running on the expected CPU-thread. I hope it is the only one running on it but at the end, my process displays:

```
Number of voluntary context switch:   2
Number of involuntary context switch: 1231
```

If I had involuntary context switches, it means that other processes are running on my core: **How is it possible? What must I do in order to get Number of involuntary context switch =  0?**

Last question: When my process is running, if I launch

```
$ cset set -l
cset: 
         Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
         root        0-7 y       0 y  1031    1 /
    my_cpuset        3,7 n       0 n     0    0 /my_cpuset
```

Once again I get 0 tasks on my CPU-set. But I know that there is a process running on it: it seems that a task is not a process?

Answer (score 1):

> **If the size of the buffers become quite big, my PC starts to slow down: why?** I have 4 cores with hyper-threading so 3 cores are remaing. Only one is 100% busy. Is it because my process uses almost 100% for the "RAM-bus"?

You reached the hardware performance limit of a single-threaded application, that is 100% CPU time on the single CPU your program is allocated to. Your application thread will not run on more than one CPU at a time [(reference)](https://superuser.com/questions/293809/can-a-single-threaded-program-be-made-to-use-multiple-cores).

> **What must I do in order to get Number of involuntary context switch = 0?**

Aren't you missing `--cpu_exclusive` option in `cset set` command?

By the way, if you want to achieve lower execution time, i suggest you to make a multithreaded application and let operating system, and the hardware beneath parallelize execution instead. Locking a process to a CPU set and preventing it from doing context-switch might degrade the operating system performance and is not a portable solution.